# How to properly use readAllLines in Java?

Tags: java, file, path, character-encoding, file.readalllines

I am trying to read every line in a file and then splitting them. It is the first time I do this and I am not sure if I am using the right Charset or path to the file. Thank you for your help! Here is my try:

The path (ruta) in main is specified like this:

```
Path ruta=FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("mapa.csv");
```

The name of my file is mapa.csv, I am trying to get to its folder. The constructor is the following:

```
public void construirMapa() {
    List<String> lineas = null;   
    try{
        //this returns null
        lineas = Files.readAllLines(ruta, Charset.defaultCharset());  
    }catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    if(lineas!=null){
        Iterator <String> linea=lineas.iterator();
        while(linea.hasNext()){
            String[] atributo=linea.next().split(";");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you are showing looks fine in general; maybe except for the thing that it does nothing with that **atributo** array that it creates. You wouldnt even notice that anything is going on there; your code would just read that file, process content ... but without any visible side effects!

Comment: Why is `ruta` specified like that? Use `Path ruta = Paths.get("mapa.csv")`

Answer (score -1):

Seems ok, also you can use the following code:

```
catch (IOException ex)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

to get stacktrace in error case